# Haskell: What's my indent error

Tags: haskell, indentation

I'm getting what I think is an indent error with the following code

```
152     -- find the first one who can refute the scenario
153     let cs = map ($scenario) [ Suspect . getWho, Room . getWhere, Weapon . getHow ]
154     let (qs,rss) = break (not . null . intersect cs . hand) ps
155     unless (null rss) $ do
156       let refuter:ss= rss
157       let valid = intersect cs $ hand refuter
158 
159       (refuter, shown) <- if cheated refuter
160                             -- if the refuter is a cheater, just choose for him
161                             then return (refuter, head valid)
162                             else do
163                               (refuter, shown) <- runStateT $ reveal scenario
164                               -- make sure they don't cheat
165                               return if shown `elem` valid
166                                         then (refuter, shown)
167                                         else (refuter { cheated = True }, head valid)
168       putTail (qs ++ refuter:ss)
169     return ()
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Game.hs:159:6:
    The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression
```

When I delete or comment out lines 159-167, the error goes away.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think this stack-exchange [proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review") might be of interest to you. If it is show your support and help get it into beta :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put parenthesis around the if-then-else in the value for `return` in line 165:

```
return (if shown `elem` valid
           then (refuter, shown)
           else (refuter { cheated = True }, head valid))
```

A pure if-then-else is not [allowed](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html) by the Haskell grammar as a function argument, it has to be put in parenthesis to be used in that place. (It is a *lexp* while a function argument has to be an *aexp*.)

The error message generated is not very helpful in finding that issue.

Answer (score 4):

```
return $ if ..
```

This should work. Matter of function application priority.